# Python raw_input is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is my code:

```
randomOne = int(str(raw_input('Enter the first number.')))
randomTwo = int(str(raw_input('Enter the second number.')))
```

I always get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/*****/Desktop/Pythons/randomNumberGenerator.py", line 5, in <module>
randomOne = int(str(raw_input('Enter the first number.')))
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined
```

I do not understand at all what is going on, if i could have some help?

Comment: what version are you on? `raw_input` was removed in Python 3, and its behavior switched to `input`.

Comment: As a side note: Why are you trying to call `str` on the result of `raw_input`? What are you expecting that to do? (In every version of Python that had `raw_input`, from 0.x to 2.7, it returns a `str`, so calling `str` on it will just make a copy.)

Comment: Meanwhile, if you're using Python 3.x, but using examples written for Python 2.x, you may want to at least skim [What's New in Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html), and bookmark it to search it whenever you have a problem like this. For example, if you search the page for `raw_input`, you'l find "PEP 3111: `raw_input()` was renamed to `input()`…"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using python 3, it doesn't have `raw_input`, use [input](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) instead.

Comment: that was more simple of a problem then i thought...*facepalm*